# Contact Patent Owner

Tags: us6328675

In reference to the patent: [US6328675](https://www.google.com/patents/US6328675)

I'm looking to get in touch with the owner of this patent, are you interested in selling?

Thank you

Kat

Answer (score 0):

It has expired. At the very bottom of the google patents page for this patent you will find -

"Feb 2, 2010   FP  Expired due to failure to pay maintenance fee
Effective date: 20091211"

Comment: That's a good point though.